# Elasticsearch boosting query with bool

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to make a bool query inside boosting query but not able to get the desired result

```
qry = {
"query" : {
        "boosting" : {
            "positive" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    {   
                        "match" : {
                            "author" : "doyle"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match" : {
                            "text" : "elementary"
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "negative" :{
                "match" : {
                    "text" : "holmes"
                }
            },
            "negative_boost" : 0.2
        }
    }
}
```

Negative part of the boosting query doesn't seem to apply as results having 'holmes' are not suppressed.

Following is the mapping of index

```
mapping = {
    "mappings" : {
        "book" : {
            "properties" : {
                "title" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "index_options" : "docs"
                },
                "author" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "index_options" : "docs"
                },
                "line_no" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                },
                "text" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "index_options" : "offsets"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```